# Can't save a node which has string cck fields

Tags: nodes

I want migrate our academic paper records from Drupal 6 to 8 manually. 
Many nodes can be stored correctly if its type has not any string field.
I tried many ways but some nodes can't be stored if it has a string field.

An example of my code as follows:

```
<?php
  use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

  $db = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'user', 'pwd');
  mysqli_select_db($db, 'academic6');
  $result = mysqli_query($db, 'select * from other_paper');
  // We have many view tables in Drupal 6 database.
  // other_papers is a view table which connects many fields.
  $count=0;
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $count++;

    $arr = [
      'type' => 'other_paper',
      'title' => $row['title'],
      'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
      'uid' => $row['user'], 
      'status' => 1,
      'promote' => 0,
      'comment' => 0,
      'created' => $row['created'],
      'changed' => $row['changed'],

      'field_year' => ['value' => $row['year']],
      //string field address holds an url address or empty string 
      'field_address' => ['value' => $row['address'] ],
      'field_old_id' => ['value' => $row['id']]
    ];
    $node = Node::create( $arr );

    $node->save();
  }
  echo $count.' saved.<br>';
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: An error didn't occurred after the script running... Output is normal "2 saved". Records on node and  node_data tables are stored. But other fields aren't stored. field_year and field_old_id are integer field types, but their data can not be stored like field_address. If I write /node#/edit to address line, following error was occurred: 
 Fatal error: Call to a member function isNewRevision() on null in ...

Comment: I found what is the problem... node type string is wrong! In program type written as "other_paper" but creation type is "other_papers" ! Problem solved. Sorry. Please delete this question record.